# Ethersjs txn.wait(1) doesnot resolves

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, javascript, ethers.js

I am trying to mint a token and wait for its minting transaction to go through.
And for this I am using the `tx.wait(NUMBER_OF_CONFIRMATIONS)` of ethersjs. from https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/types/#providers-TransactionResponse

And we are running the whole process of minting the nft in firebase cloud functions.

This is how I've implemented the mint function in the contract(if its relevant)

```
function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount, string memory _tokenURI) public{
        require(hasRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender), "Only Admin can call this function!");
        tokenId += 1;
        s_supply[tokenId] += _amount;
        s_tokenIdToURI[tokenId] = _tokenURI;
        _mint(_to, tokenId, _amount, "");
        emit NftMinted(_to, tokenId, _amount, _tokenURI);
    }
```

Below is the how I am making the function call on my smart contract

```
const bridgeMintingTxn = await bridgeNftContract.mint(
              BRIDGE_SINGLE_TOKEN_LOCKER_POLYGON,
              1,
              tokenURI,
              {gasLimit: 10000000}
          );
```

And this is how I am waiting for confirmation of the transaction
`await bridgeMintingTxn.wait(1);`

But this .wait(1) call is not resolving 7 out of 10 times.

Can any one point out any mistake I'm making here. Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so in my case it was the not the problem of ethersjs, but my RPC URL that I was using was not functioning properly. It was not sending the transactions properly and same goes for receiving their confirmations. Changing the RPC URL worked for me.